# How to get right slide to work on a button click in android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

Hey i found very nice lib [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) which helps in implementing the sliding in android. The problem is, using this lib i am able to achive toggling at one side at a time i.e either on left or right.

I want to implement toggling on both sides i.e if i click on left side button i want left view to appear and similarly right view should appear if i click on right button.

I also got one branch from the same author i,e [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/slidingright). In this we have the option to specify at toggle weather to go left or right.

We need to merge these together and use it. but i'm confused like which function to pick even though both have same names & should i overwrite or not?. really confused what to do. any help??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is an older version of the library, you can still specify which sliding mode you want in the current version like this:

```
 SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
 menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
```

This will set it to a left sliding menu, you can however also specify `SlidingMenu.RIGHT` for right or `SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT` for both.

So just use the [current version](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thanks for your reply. But i have a problem. i have two buttons. one left and right. In this case how to toggle

Comment: Toggle does not takes any params i.e left or right. based on the type what you set in SlidingMenu object it works. even if i click on right side button and call toggle(), left view only comes according to ur code

Comment: No its not working :(... i tried creating two instances of Slidingmenu one for left and right, tried to call toggle() but  didnt work :(.. any idea apart from this?

Comment: No unfortunately not :/ I'll inform you if I can come up with something though!

Comment: Sure, i have read that, we need to merge the later one with latest code.. any way ill try.. thanks pls let me know if u come up with any hint

Comment: u are right, i set fresh menu and tried by calling showSecondaryMenu() it worked... thanks lot... but i have one problem when right slide takes place the effect is not exactly similar to left one i.e gradient effect is bit varied.  how to make it look similar

Comment: You can use showMenu(true) and showSecondaryMenu(true) to animate to the left and right menus, respectively. If you want to shadows to be the same, use the drawables provided in the project: setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow) and setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright)